# Generic Interface autowaring in Spring

Tags: java, spring, generics, dependency-injection

I created a generic interface and several parameterized implementations for it. Then I try to inject a class implementing this interface with a concrete type via the @Autoware annotation but fail.

I create an interface:

```
public interface DataParser<T> {
     T parse(List<String> objectList);
}
```

and realisation :

```
@Component
public class DataItemParserImpl implements DataParser<Item> {
    @Override
    public Item parse(List<String> objectList) {
```

when I try to Autoware bean like this

```
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataItemParserImpl")
    public DataParser<Item> itemDataParser;
```

I doesn't get any error, but object itemDataParser is NULL.
What's the catch? I'm thinking about type erasure. How to fix, optimize?